# Using "of" for adjective constructions

Tags: adjectives, of-phrases

> The algorithm has O(N) time-complexity.

It seems I can write the above sentence as:

> The algorithm has the time-complexity **of** O(N)

In general, in what cases can I use "of" to rephrase an adjective construction?

Comment: Yes, in many cases it's possible, especially when the adjective phrase has nouns in it.  "Eglish grammar lessons" -> "lessons of English grammar".

Comment: @VictorBazarov That particular one is unidiomatic; we'd ordinarily say *lessons **in** English grammar*.

Comment: Here is another "the boys troop leader" -> "the leader of the troop of boys".  Does this one work OK?

Comment: VictorBazarov That one's fine.

Comment: @StoneyB As I have seen in my academic field,  It is common to say that "The Algorithms Complexity is of **order** of O( N)" or "Complexity **order** of ", I mean they have used the word "order", too

Comment: @Cardinal. I've never heard or read "... *is of order **of** O(N)*".  BTW, doesn't the "O-notation" actually mean "Order" (and that's why it uses the capital letter O)?

Comment: @VictorBazarov I know the O. Try google with "Complexity is of order of ". However, I know O refers to **order**. I was talking about the word "order". perhaps, I was successful to imply my point.

Comment: @VictorBazarov I mean "is of order of N == O(N)"